# Ajax object with PHP variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, object

Is there any possible format to add write this...

PHP:

```
wp_localize_script( 'script', 'script_object_' . $ID, array(  'name' => whatever ) );
....
echo '<form onsubmit=\'myfunction("'. $ID .'"); return false\'>'
```

JS:

```
function myfunction( ID ){
alert( script_object_ + ID +.name );
}
```

Some way to write in js ???

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: script_object_ + ID +.name <= bad wrote. I'm looking for de correct way

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_localize_script( 'script', 'script_object_' . $ID, array(  'name' => whatever ) );
....
echo "<form onsubmit='myfunction(\"script_object_".$ID."\", ".json_encode(array(  'name' => whatever ))."); return false'>";


function myfunction( elname, json ){
    alert( elname );
    console.log(json)

    var json2 = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(json2);
}
```

or if you prefer:

Comment: I need the content in array, that form not return :(

Comment: @tyler_dev, please accept the answer if it is what you were looking for.